# How to generate an activation link in an email via a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a way to validate emails in order to not choke up our queue. The goal is that when a user is finished with their account setup, the email needs to be validated. My idea is to create a stored procedure that will send an email to the one the user put with a link or something to verify that the email has been sent and opened.

What I am confused with is how to generate this link.

In one of my tables that stores users, I added a column named 'isActive' with type BIT and set to 0. The goal is for the email to have a link where once clicked, will flip the 'isActive' column from 0 to 1, this will verify if the email was reached properly.

I expect that when the user is done entering his info, the stored procedure will send an email to verify that the email is correct by clicking on an activation link.

Comment: Is the question about how to generate a unique identifier for this column row to identify this validation request specifically relates to one account, or do you need to know how to do the entire process of email validation from start to finish? Odds are that you aren't going to have the server itself send the email or generate the link, but you can probably have the server generate the key or details that would go into said link/email.

edit: I mean you _could_ have the server generate the entire link, but it seems like an odd place to put that logic.

Comment: Bingo, guess I was too vague in my explanation. Generating a unique identifier is what has me scratching my head. @CodyMcPheron

Comment: Aside: You should associate an expiration date/time with the unique link so that it is only valid for a reasonable period, e.g. 30 minutes. It may also be helpful to keep a `DateTime` field `ActivatedOn` rather than a `bit`. If it is `null` then the account hasn't been activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment clarification above, I'm thinking you would want to set one column to a GUID (or add a new column). These links will provide some details about how and why to do this, but the short version is that you can guarantee that the join key is not guessable and is always unique. Set a column to have a default GUID value via UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() and it will create a new ID with every new row that you can use in other sections of your code.

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-guid/

https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-guid-data-type-in-sql-server/